# Framerate error when i exporting FBX file

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, blender, frame-rate, fbx

When exporting a fbx file with animation from a blender for unity3D, the animation does not work and its framerate becomes 0 and an error appears in the console
"Model 'Fan' contains animation clip 'BFan|Armature.001Action.002' which has length of 0 frames (start=0, end=1). It will result in empty animation. "
"ImportFBX Errors:Framerate was set to 0.00, it's been reset to 1.0."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIbXA.png)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the frame rate in blender is lower than what you have set in Unity. Try changing the FPS in blender to 60.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this since the recent blender update, fixed for me by making sure in export to fbx I have the "bake animation" checked, and if you have no animations, you can expand the bake animation section and uncheck the 4 sub-checkboxes but keep sample rate at 1.00 and simplify at 1.00.

Answer (score 0):

I found that appending the objects from the source .blend file to a new one fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error.
When exporting the .fbx to unity I got a "FBX import error, framerate 0, reset to 1"
The animations were totally broken and only a few fps of random garbage data.

**What fixed for me**

I used Frame Rate 30 FPS on blender's output properties.
For some reason this was breaking the export.
I turned framerate back to the default 24 FPS and now everything exported fine to unity.

Really weird. I think this should be a bug with the fbx exporter of some plugin weirdness. Using Blender 3.3.0.

Comment: Experiencing the same thing here Blender 3.3.1 when exporting at 30 FPS it has a super low framerate, but 24 FPS is fine and 60 FPS is fine however my animation is designed for 30 FPS not 24 FPS so I might have to scale it for 60 FPS and export at 60 FPS. A bit unfortunate but hopefully it'll get the job done.

Comment: Just upgraded to Blender 3.4.0 and this issue seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

hi all i change my blender version and work for me the version 3.4.1